# gRPC: CMake install does not copy .pdb files

Tags: c++, grpc, grpc-c++

I'm currently using gRPC 1.62.1 on my Windows 10 machine with VS 2019.

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md but after the debug build was successful the CMake install does not copy the .pdb files. (The .pdb files will be created during the build)

Following commands have been used:

```
mkdir _build
mkdir _install
mkdir _install\debug
mkdir _install\release
cmake -B"./_build" -H"." -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\flag\Downloads\grpc-1.62.1\grpc\_install\debug -DABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD=ON -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON
cmake --build ./_build --target install --config=Debug
```

Also tried this but same effect.

```
cmake -B"./_build" -H"." -DABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD=ON
cmake --build ./_build --target install --config=Debug
```

Maybe someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Is it a bug report? Then report a bug at the upstream bug tracker. Do you want help getting `cmake` to install it? Set a "cmake" tag on the question, preferably removing the others. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: you can try to add manually this line foe each target installed into the group `gRPCTargets` : `install(DIRECTORY
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:address_sorting>/
    DESTINATION "${gRPC_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.pdb"
  )`